# nginx certbot doesnt redirect to django server

Tags: django, nginx

Im trying to set-up SSL sertificate for Django. I set up it by this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYdv6pkCufk&ab_channel=TonyTeachesTech, in the guide django server just start working with SSL, but for me is not working, but rederecting domain from http to https, but not redirecting to django server. I dont even know what to do. I search in entire internet and find nothing.

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name wavera.ru www.wavera.ru; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.wavera.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.wavera.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}server {
    if ($host = wavera.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.wavera.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    server_name wavera.ru www.wavera.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

i starting server by

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Comment: so your Django is running on localhost:8000, where in your nginx conf you are forwarding your request to that address?

Comment: The requested URL is www.wavera.ru/abc/something and your Django is running on localhost:8000/abc/something.  you are also missing the location block in your Nginx setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runserver is for development purposes only, You should run something like **gunicorn** to create a .sock file.

For now, you can try something like -

```
upstream backend {
    server localhost:8000;
}
server {
        server_name wavera.ru www.wavera.ru;
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://backend 
     }
```

}

for https, try-

```
server {
        server_name wavera.ru www.wavera.ru;
           location / {
            include proxy_params;
               proxy_pass http://backend
        }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.wavera.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.wavera.ru/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = wavera.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    if ($host = www.wavera.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    listen 80 ;
    server_name wavera.ru www.wavera.ru;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I try to paste this code into my nginx config and server still not runing. I'll go to learn about gunicorn / wsgi and try to run it another time with more information, because at this point i literally doenst understand what nginx want from me.

Comment: Have you restarted nginx  ?

Comment: oh.. forgot about that. now it working with HTTP only, is it possible to set this config to redirect to https?

Comment: Yes, wait I will update my answer.

Comment: if you update answer, please add " } " in the end of the answer code and " ; " after proxy pass string :)

Comment: listen 443 ssl, will make your server block listen only to https.

Comment: oh my god now its working!!!!!! thank you so much!!! if its not difficult for you ,can you give some good links about how to set up gunicorn with nginx and about how to set up and understand nginx?

Comment: Keep looking for content in SO, keep trying, updating, and improving your conf files,  that's how I learnt.  Glad it helps you.  I don't have any good gunicorn setup docs links now.

Comment: i just trying to set up this server correctly about are week. now its working. thank you so much for you time and for you help!

Comment: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) look at this, it might help you.

Comment: also, you can add return 444 and remove the return statement from your default server so that it blocks access coming from the IP address of the server rather than the domain name.